# How do I get the Guayadeque icon to work with the indicator applet in Gnome Classic?

Tags: gnome-classic

The taskbar icon keeps popping up right over my close window buttons in Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Classic.

Is there a way to get it in the indicator applet, or to remember where I place it?

Also, is there a way to get it to remember it's "always on top" setting?

It's kinda annoying for it to fall behind other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAY! I found the problem! It was so simple I actually feel dumber for finding the solution. :P

The "Notification Area" applet is what controls the "legacy" icons. It also fixed a few other icons that were missing for other apps.